# unclickable ionic rating for average

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<rating ng-model="newRate.rating" max="max" class="assertive"></rating>
```

How to make ionic rating not clickable?
Needed for displaying the average values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it read only, try this:

added readonly="readOnly" to rating directive, and $scope.readOnly = true; to the controller.